# Enable button if at least one checkbox is selected and with checkbox select all

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script that enables a button if at least one checkbox is selected and a checkbox selects all.

The problem is that I can't make it work correctly, when I select the checkbox select all it activates the button but if I uncheck it it is not deactivating.

The delete checkboxes are working correctly the problem is in select all

```js
var checa = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");
var numElementos = checa.length;
var bt = document.getElementById("btn");
for(var x=0; x<numElementos; x++){
   checa[x].onclick = function(){
      // "input[name='toggle']:checked" conta os checkbox checados
      var cont = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle:checked").length;
      // ternário que verifica se há algum checado.
      // se não há, retorna 0 (false), logo desabilita o botão
      bt.disabled = cont ? false : true;
   }
}

//---------------------------------------

var roles = {
    checkall: {
        delete: true
    }
};

 $('.role').click(function() {
     var result = {};
     $('.role').each(function() {
         if (!$(this).prop('checked')) return;
         var role = $(this).attr('id');
         $.extend(result, roles[role]);
     });
     $('.perm').each(function() {
         var perm = $(this).attr('id');
         var chk = (perm in result);
         $(this).prop('checked', chk);
     });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container card m-4 p-3">

<div>
<input class="role toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="checkall"/>Select all
</div>
<hr />
<div class="mb-1">
<input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete"/>Delete 1
</div>
<div class="mb-1">
<input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete"/>Delete 2
</div>
<div class="mb-1">
<input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete"/>Delete 3
</div>
<div class="mb-1">
<input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete"/>Delete 4
</div>
<div class="mb-1">
<input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete"/>Delete 5
</div>
<div class="mb-1">
<input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete"/>Delete 6
</div>
<hr />
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btn" disabled> Delete selected</button> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one element per document with any given `id`. `id`
 **must** be unque.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your checkboxes have the same id's. Change id to something else for each checkbox... like delete1, delete2... what else.

If your id factor is the same. Javascript considers it all same. Although...

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
var checa = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");
var numElementos = checa.length;
var bt = document.getElementById("btn");
for (var x = 0; x < numElementos; x++) {
  checa[x].onclick = function() {
    // "input[name='toggle']:checked" conta os checkbox checados
    var cont = $(".toggle:checked").length;
    // ternário que verifica se há algum checado.
    // se não há, retorna 0 (false), logo desabilita o botão
    bt.disabled = cont > 0 ? false : true;
  }
}

//---------------------------------------

var roles = {
  checkall: {
    delete: true
  }
};

$('.role').click(function() {
  var result = {};
  $('.role').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop('checked')) return;
    var role = $(this).attr('id');
    $.extend(result, roles[role]);
  });
  $('.perm').each(function() {
    var perm = $(this).attr('id');
    var chk = (perm in result);
    $(this).prop('checked', chk);
  });
  var cont = $(".toggle:checked").length;
  bt.disabled = cont > 0 ? false : true;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container card m-4 p-3">

  <div>
    <input class="role toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="checkall" />Select all
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="mb-1">
    <input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete" />Delete 1
  </div>
  <div class="mb-1">
    <input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete" />Delete 2
  </div>
  <div class="mb-1">
    <input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete" />Delete 3
  </div>
  <div class="mb-1">
    <input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete" />Delete 4
  </div>
  <div class="mb-1">
    <input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete" />Delete 5
  </div>
  <div class="mb-1">
    <input class="perm toggle me-2" type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="delete" />Delete 6
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btn" disabled> Delete selected</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now :)